# XSLT: Get previous node value within text tokenized template

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm new in XSLT so I hope I'll get some help here.

I'm trying to transform following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl"?>
    <OrderLineItems>
    <OrderLineItem>
        <SKU>60</SKU>
        <Meta>Topic: one, Topic: two, Topic: three, Topic: four</Meta>
    </OrderLineItem>
    <OrderLineItem>
        <SKU>70</SKU>
        <Meta>Topic: one, Topic: two, Topic: three, Topic: four</Meta>
    </OrderLineItem>
    </OrderLineItems>
```

to

```
<ArticleNo>60.1</ArticleNo>
<ArticleNo>60.2</ArticleNo>
<ArticleNo>60.3</ArticleNo>
<ArticleNo>60.4</ArticleNo>

<ArticleNo>70.1</ArticleNo>
<ArticleNo>70.2</ArticleNo>
<ArticleNo>70.3</ArticleNo>
<ArticleNo>70.4</ArticleNo>
```

with following xslt which doesn't work

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="Meta" name="tokenize">
        <xsl:param name="separator" select="', '" />
        <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(.,$separator)">
                            <ArticleNo><xsl:value-of select="../SKU"/>.<xsl:value-of select="position()" /></ArticleNo>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="SKU" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How can I access SKU correctly?

Comment: `tokenize()` is a `XSLT 2.0` function and not available in `XSLT 1.0`. Can you upgrade to `XSLT 2.0`?

Answer (score 2):

Using `XSLT 2.0` the output can be achieved by making a small tweak in the shared XSL. The `<SKU>` value can be added to a variable and used to format the desired output.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="Meta" name="tokenize">
        <xsl:param name="separator" select="', '" />
        <xsl:variable name="skuValue" select="../SKU" />
        <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(.,$separator)">
            <ArticleNo>
                <xsl:value-of select="$skuValue" />
                .
                <xsl:value-of select="position()" />
            </ArticleNo>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="SKU" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
<ArticleNo>60.1</ArticleNo>
<ArticleNo>60.2</ArticleNo>
<ArticleNo>60.3</ArticleNo>
<ArticleNo>60.4</ArticleNo>
<ArticleNo>70.1</ArticleNo>
<ArticleNo>70.2</ArticleNo>
<ArticleNo>70.3</ArticleNo>
<ArticleNo>70.4</ArticleNo>
```

Comment: Don't know why but when I try your solution it doesn't work. I always get 'net.sf.saxon.s9api.SaxonApiException: Errors were reported during stylesheet compilation'. Maybe you need my full example

Comment: I am using `saxon9he.jar` for processing.

Comment: If the answer has worked for you, could you please accept the answer. [How to accept the answer and it's benefits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)